# What is the significance of the scene between Mrs. Potts and Maurice at the end of Beauty and the Beast?

Tags: analysis, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In *Beauty and the Beast* (2017), there is a knowing look at the end between Mrs. Potts and Maurice who does a double take back at her. What was that about?

Answer (score 6):

It's a moment that comes from the original animated film.

Basically, Mrs Potts fancies Maurice, and lets him know it with a look.

Maurice's double-take is him going (in his mind), "Mrs Potts seems to like me... wait, what?!"

It was a little more obvious in the original animation, with the look being one of mutual appreciation.  A lot of people picked up on it.

[image: Barry White plays in the background]

[image: Maurice with that "hey sexy" look]

Comment: But she's married in the new movie. In the cartoon she wasn't protrayed to have a husband so it was ok. Now the look is just weird in the movie.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's more of a glance of recognition because Ms. Potts acted as a mother like figure to Belle while she was the castle and Maurice appreciates that. They can look at each other like that because they both love Belle and Maurice appreciates Ms. Potts' kindness.